# Cannot browse hard drives in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my primary hard drive.  I have Windows 10 Home installed on my secondary hard drive.  My default boot is Ubuntu.  If I want to boot to Windows, I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to select boot order to my secondary hard drive.  Everything was fine until Computer (Ubuntu) and my secondary computer (can't recall label) disappeared. I can no longer browse primary or secondary hard drives. I have phrased my problem every way I can think up, but could not find the answer. Now I am going to Ask Ubuntu.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume this happened after the move to Ubuntu 18.04. Have you checked "Other Locations" in the file manager's sidebar? You could also open Disks utility from the app menu to see if your hard drive is shown. If it is, then it's probably not mounted.

Comment: I believe OP is talking about BIOS startup screen before Ubuntu and even `grub` is loaded.

Comment: I think the OP needs to clarify this. I doubt they mean the BIOS startup screen. If they do, then it probably doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu. "before...even grub is loaded" you suggest.

Comment: I believe on Dell systems you press `F12` to change BIOS boot order.